# How to get JSON.parser value after save to AsyncStorage using Json.stringfy in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage, jsonparser

I want to use the data from JSON.stringify that I save locally from async storage, so I can manage them locally (like user data for login)

I already save it to AsyncStorage

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
      fetch('My_url', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
         this.setState({
            data: responseJson
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });

   }

   saveData = async () => {
     try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
                Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
            }
```

this is the JSON

```
0   
username    "admin2"
password    "*****"
access  "1"
name    "dwi"
phone_number    "087613721"
email   "**@****.com"
score   null
status  "0"
1   
username    "admin3"
password    "***"
access  "1"
name    "Satria"
phone_number    "****"
email   "*****3@*****.com"
score   null
status  "0"
```

and I try to get the value using this, but can't show anything in node console.log, it said "unidentified" (i just using press button on this)

```
displayData = async ()=>{
    try{
      let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      let parsed = JSON.parse(user);
      console.log(parsed.email);
    }
    catch(error){
      alert(error)
    }
  }
```

can some JSON parser output use like to be database function? 
like for login so we can log in and check the data user from json.parser that I store in the data using async storage?
or output some data that we want to be used like in where statement in the SQL ?

Comment: can you put it in an expo snack for us to check

Comment: i have so many library like native-base , it is possible to share that ?

Comment: What's the result if you do `console.log(user)` ?

Comment: @vitosorriso it has output json that i store like in the top

Comment: I think the data is an array of Object. Try to print the value like this  `console.log(parsed[0].email)`

Answer (score 0):

The response of `await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');` is an array like `[key,value]`.
You need write `parsed[0]` to get key and `JSON.parse(parsed[1])` to get json value.